# checking if all digits in an array element are 0 or 1 [c++]

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, binary

I need to check if all digits in the one element in array = 0 or 1.

I have functions for this:

```
bool checkIfBin(int okt) {
    while (okt > 0)
    {
        int digit = okt % 10;

        if (digit > 1)
            return false;
        okt /= 10;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and calling this function looks like:

```
for (int j=0; j < 4; j++) {
        cout << "Enter" << j+1 << " octet in binary system: ";
        
        if (checkIfBin(okt[j]) == true)
            cin >> okt[j];
        else
            break;
    }
```

the problem is that - it doesn't stop program from looping when the function returns false. I've debugged functions and it seems to work fine, but I'm just learning and I could have done it wrong. does not receive any errors.

I don't know where the problem is

Comment: Checking a number *before* reading it seems a bit backwards. (It looks like you got the correct parts but assembled them in the wrong order.)

Comment: `if (a == true)` is the same as `if (a)`.

Comment: Move the `cin >> ...` above the test, change the test to `if (!checkIfBin(okt[j]) break;` and remove the `else` handler entirely.

Comment: I have a function declaration before main and functions at the end

Comment: @ŁukaszStrama .. that has absolutely *nothing* to do with this issue. just look at your code, line by line and try explaining it to yourself.

Comment: @ŁukaszStrama If that was a response to me, I was not referring to the definition of the function, but to how you're using it.

Comment: *"I've debugged functions"* -- then you should be able to answer this: what is the value of `okt` inside `checkIfBin()` when you are expecting the program to stop looping? (Not just what you expect it to be, but what it actually is.)

Comment: @JaMiT exactly, a simple `cout` statement inside the function should make the issue obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that You are checking the input before reading it.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
{
    cout << "Enter" << j+1 << " octet in binary system: ";

    cin >> okt[j];

    if (!checkIfBin(okt[j]))
        break;
}
```

should work beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all of you for the answers,
especially @WhozCraig

```
for (int j=0; j < 4; j++) {
        cout << "Enter" << j+1 << " octet in binary system: ";
        
        cin >> okt[j];

        if ((!checkIfBin(okt[j])) break; 
    }
```

works fine